# I'm trying to either copy banding format or apply only to visible data, Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I'm working on and I'm writing a code to copy select tabs and paste them as values/formatting into a new workbook that I can share with users and allow them to edit some fields.  I need to move the data to a new sheet because my data sheet includes `QUERY()` functions that I don't want the users to be able to break, but I want the users to be able to filter and add notes as necessary.  The final step that I can't get to work correctly is the banding/alternating colors format.  They apparently don't save as backgroundcolor so that doesn't copy over.

```
function exportToDashboard() {
  var fromSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
    "myURL"
  );

  var fromSheet = fromSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contact Summary.DASH");
  var toSheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contact Summary.DASH");
  var fromRange = fromSheet.getRange("A1:E");
  var values = fromRange.getValues();
 //  var banding = fromRange.getBandings();
  var colors = fromRange.getFontColors();
  var fontstyle = fromRange.getFontWeights();
  var fontsizes = fromRange.getFontSizes();
  var toRange = toSheet.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length);

  toRange.clearContent();
  toRange.getBandings().forEach(function (banding) {
    banding.remove();
  });
  toRange.setValues(values);
//  toRange.applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.GREEN);
  toRange.setFontColors(colors);
  toRange.setFontSizes(fontsizes);
  toRange.setFontWeights(fontstyle);
```

I want the source banding to carry over, but when I try and use the defined variable `banding` the `applyRowBanding()` function doesn't work and gives an error.  I can use `applyRowBanding`(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.GREEN) to apply the banding theme that I want, but it applies to the entire columns and not only to my data (where I want it to stay).  Because alternating color formatting is not stored as a cell background color, I'm not able to copy that piece of format and paste it over either.

Really I just want to either copy or set the banding to my data only.